# SSJS: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, httprequest, httppost

I'm trying to create a script to store values from a form on a cloud page in the SFMC database using the SSJS HTTP Post method, but I'm receiving the following error:

> Exception occurred: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.

It appears that something is missing from the script. I tried other solutions to fix this issue but nothing worked. Please find my code below.

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1");

  function getAccessToken() {
    var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows(
      "TriggeredSendDataExtension",
      "100001000"
    );

    if (dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
      Write(
        "Integration credentials found. Retrieving Access Token ..." +
          "<br><br>"
      );
      clientId = dataRows[0]["ClientID"];
      clientSecret = dataRows[0]["ClientSecret"];
      accountId = dataRows[0]["AccountID"].replace(/ /g, "");
      tenantId = dataRows[0]["TenantID"];

      var payload =
        '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": "' +
        clientId +
        '", "client_secret": "' +
        clientSecret +
        '","account_id": "' +
        accountId +
        '"}';

      var authurl =
        "https://" + tenantId + ".auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";

      var contentType = "application/json";

      var result = HTTP.Post(authurl, contentType, payload);
      console.log("Result : ", result);
      var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
      console.log("Content : ", content);
      return content;
    } else
      Write(
        "No valid integration credendtials found. Please contact your admin" +
          "<br><br>"
      );
  }

  try {
    var jsonResp = getAccessToken();
    var authToken = jsonResp.access_token;
    var restURL = jsonResp.rest_instance_url;
    Write("Access Token = " + authToken + "<br>");
    Write("Rest URL = " + restURL + "<br><br>");

    var customer_name = "John Doe";
    var company_name = "ABC";
    var EmailAddress = "jdoe@email.com";
    var Product_Name1 = "Adidas Shirt";
    var Product_Quantity1 = "25";
    var Customization1 = "Embroidery";
    var Product_Name2 = "Under Armour Cap";
    var Product_Quantity2 = "24";
    var Customization2 = "Logo";

    console.log(
      "Form values: ",
      customer_name,
      " ",
      company_name,
      " ",
      EmailAddress,
      " ",
      Product_Name1,
      " ",
      Product_Quantity1,
      " ",
      Customization1,
      " ",
      Product_Name2,
      " ",
      Product_Quantity2,
      " ",
      Customization2
    );

    //Build out details for Triggered Send Post Request
    var payload = '{"To": {';
    payload += '"Address": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
    payload += '"SubscriberKey": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
    payload += '"ContactAttributes": {';
    payload += '"SubscriberAttributes": {';
    payload += '"SubscriberKey": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
    payload += '"EmailAddress": "' + EmailAddress + '",';
    payload += '"Customer Name": "' + customer_name + '",';
    payload += '"Company Name": "' + company_name + '",';
    payload += '"Product_Name1": "' + Product_Name1 + '",';
    payload += '"Product_Quantity1": "' + Product_Quantity1 + '",';
    payload += '"Customization1": "' + Customization1 + '",';
    payload += '"Product_Name2": "' + Product_Name2 + '",';
    payload += '"Product_Quantity2": "' + Product_Quantity2 + '",';
    payload += '"Customization2": "' + Customization2 + '",';
    payload += "}}}}";

    var apiRoute, bearerToken;

    apiRoute = restURL + "messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:XXXXXX/send";
    bearerToken = "Bearer " + authToken;

    var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
    var headerValues = [bearerToken];

    var restResponse = HTTP.Post(
      apiRoute,
      "application/json",
      payload,
      headerNames,
      headerValues
    );

    Write("Triggered Send POST Request: " + "<br>");
    Write("Status Code: " + restResponse.StatusCode + "<br>");
    Write("Response: " + restResponse.StatusCode + "<br>");
  } catch (e) {
    Write("Exception occured: " + e + "<br>");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, can you narrow the problem down? Half of the code you share is  a function `getAccessToken`- does this function work on its own? Does your try-catch work when you comment out the restResponse = HTTP Post line? In two, three debug steps you can narrow this down to likely a few lines of code. Please keep in mind we cannot do these tests for you from the outside.

Comment: Thank you @JonasLamberty for all your help. I narrowed down the problem and realized that clientId and clientSecret aren't being fetched in the try catch block. The issue is now resolved.